# Filtering array in angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am looking into how to filter an array with data in Angular 2 with typescript. The filtering is for an searchbar in Ionic 2, the list in the template is getting the data and is displayed, but the filtering will not work.

```
initializeItems(i:number) {
 this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='+this.placeid+'&key=AIzaSyBPi-ayuvkTht4wddCcvcy0l2wIBdT9P2w').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  this.locations[i]._detail = data.result;

  this.names.push([
    {
      name: this.locations[i]._detail.name,
      adress: this.locations[i]._detail.formatted_address,
      phone: this.locations[i]._detail.formatted_phone_number
    }
  ]);

  this.items = this.names;
  console.log(this.items);
 });
}

getItems(ev) {
  this.items = this.names;
  console.log(this.items);
  // set val to the value of the ev target
  var val = ev.target.value;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
      return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
  }
}
```

---

When i type in the searchbar i get this error.

[image]

Comment: User are assuming `item.name` refers to a string. How sure are you about that?

Comment: item.name is a string, but i don't no how to access it in the filter?

Comment: Can you try declaring `val` with `let`? i.e. `let val = ev.target.value;`

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

1. Changed the keys into strings in the object
2. added [0] in the return statement
3. Changed the array to orginames and set items = orginames, this ensures that the array will not be empty if you search and the delete the word again.

---

```
initializeItems(i:number) {
this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='+this.placeid+'&key=AIzaSyBPi-ayuvkTht4wddCcvcy0l2wIBdT9P2w').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  this.locations[i]._detail = data.result;


  this.orginames.push([
    {
      "name": this.locations[i]._detail.name,
      "adress": this.locations[i]._detail.formatted_address,
      "phone": this.locations[i]._detail.formatted_phone_number
    }
  ]);

  this.items = this.orginames;
  // this.orginames.push(this.locations[i]._detail.name);

});
console.log(this.items);

}

getItems(ev) {
  this.items = this.orginames;
  //console.log(this.items);
  // set val to the value of the ev target
  var val = ev.target.value;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
      return (item[0].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are applying `push` wrong. Push the object into array not another array. If you have multiple names use `spread` operator

```
  this.names.push(
    {
      name: this.locations[i]._detail.name,
      adress: this.locations[i]._detail.formatted_address,
      phone: this.locations[i]._detail.formatted_phone_number
    }
  );
```

Comment: How do i use the spread operator? I am new to angular 2 and typescript.

Comment: for understanding spread operator check out this doc. With this you can push all elements of an array to another array ``array.push(...anotherArray)`` . Its a JS operator . https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator